# subdirectories within ember controller not working

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-controllers

from this post it seems that sub directories within ember controller should work.

https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/1219

however its not working for me .

here is my code branch like (directory cm contains a child directory views):

```
 /controllers/cm/views/item.js
 /routes/cm/views/item.js
 /templates/cm/views/item.js
```

when i try to populate the model in route using the code below i see the data but when i put the same code in controller it never gets executed.

```
   model: function(){

            return this.store.find('item',{id: "1"});

          }
```

entry in router.js is as follows:

```
   this.resource('cm', {path: '/cm/:id'} , function() {

                this.route('views');
                this.route('views.items', {path: '/views/items'});
       });
```

Clearly ember is not able to resolve the controller correctly.
  Not sure how to fix this ...

Answer (score 0):

That its becuase the `model` hook in a `route` works differently than in the controller.

in a `route` it is a method that can return a promise, the route will wait for the promise to be resolved before setting up the controller.

in the controller, it is just an attribute, which won't get executed until you `get`it, and even then, all you will get its a promise.

Comment: I do fetch the model attribute in the template and display it in the template..i have used similar code when i get model data from controller and they work fine.. the only difference in this case is that here items.js controller resides inside /controllers/cm/views..ember is not able to resolve bcoz of the sub-directory it seems..

Answer (score 0):

Wat?!  Subdirectories work just fine.  First, I'm not sure it's the best idea to use `views` or `items` as route names, as they're both very generic, and also used in some of the ember internals and can confuse things.  Declaring a model called `View` could very well even break things in your app.

The controller/route/template structures for your `router.js` will be as follows:

```
<controllers|routes|templates>/cm.js
<controllers|routes|templates>/cm/index.js
<controllers|routes|templates>/cm/views.js
```

And I'm not sure what views.items would look like, because this would probably be better suited to making views a resource instead, or using a dash in the name, in which case the route declaration would be `this.route('views-items', {path: '/views/items'});`

Overall, I think your router definition should look like so:

```
this.resource('cms', function() {
  this.resource('cm', {path: '/:cm_id'}, function() {
    this.route('views');
    this.route('views-items', { path: '/views/items' });
  });
});
```

This isn't meant to be a quip--I'm here to help--but I think you need to spend a little more time with Ember's routing documentation to understand the conventions that Ember is expecting for certain router definitions.  Also, the ember inspector tool is a really great asset when debugging router issues: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ember-inspector/bmdblncegkenkacieihfhpjfppoconhi